# Problem using AJAX to import image from MySQL blob into HTML file input type

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

The title sounds confusing so first I'll elaborate. I have a website that among other things allows the users to upload pictures from their phones which go to a MySQL database and are stored in a blob format which works fine. I also have a button that runs an AJAX function which allows the user to import information from said MySQL database and then return it to the same HTML fields (continue where they left off kind of thing). This AJAX function works for everything but the "file" HTML input field type which I use for the pictures.

To get the file data into MySQL I use `addslashes(file_get_contents($image));` which I'm guessing I have to undo to be able to put it back in the file input field. If that is the case I don't know how to do it. My guess is that the file data is stored in the HTML input field type in one format and in the MySQL in another, but I'm not even sure of that let alone how to fix that if that indeed is the issue.

Here's a few various bits if they help.

HTML / AJAX:

```
<button type="button" id = 'ajaxButton' onClick = 'imAnAjaxFunction()';>TEST</button>

<label for="Image1"> Picture 01: </label>
<input type="file" id="Image1" name="Image1" value="Image1" 

<script>
function imAnAjaxFunction()
{   
var val1 = $('#Serial').val(); //
var request = $.ajax({
    url: 'import.php',
    type: 'get',
    data: { Serial: val1 }, //
    dataType: 'html'
});

request.done( function ( data ) {
    //alert(data);
});

request.fail( function ( jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log( 'Sorry: ' + textStatus );
});

var val1 = $('#Serial').val(); //
$.ajax
({
    url: 'import.php',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: { Serial: val1 }, //
    success: function(response)
    {
        var len = response.length;
        for(var i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            document.getElementById('DateSet').value = response[i].DateSet;
            document.getElementById('JobName').value = response[i].JobName;
            document.getElementById('Image1').value = response[i].Image1;
        }
    }
})

}
</script>
```

insert.php most of it I don't think is relevent

```
$image = $_FILES['Image1']['tmp_name'];
$imagetmp=addslashes(file_get_contents($image));
```

import.php

```
<?php
ob_start();

$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM setcrewreport WHERE Serial = '$_GET[Serial]'";

$result = $conn->query($sql); //query

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
{
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $Serial = $row['Serial'];
    $DateSet = $row['DateSet'];
    $JobName = $row['JobName'];
    $Image1   = $row['Image1'];

    $return_arr[] = array("Serial" => $Serial,
                          "DateSet" => $DateSet,
                          "JobName" => $JobName,
                          "Image1" => $Image1);
}
ob_end_clean();
// Encoding array in JSON format
echo json_encode($return_arr);
}
else
{
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

How close is this to parameterizing the SQL statement?

```
$sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM setcrewreport WHERE Serial = ?");
$sql ->bind_param("si", '$_GET[Serial]');
```

Comment: If you want an advise: don't save pictures in a database, the database gets huge and it's performance will plunge. It's way better to save only the path of the picture or the info you need to get that path and keep your databases clean of clutter

Comment: By the way, it's also better to learn to use prepared statements than to use the addslashes function to prevent your database from memory injection attacks

Comment: @jeprubio The database information is only held for a week until it is purged. It's a temporary holding location until it is imported into an Excel file. So while not ideal it works for my purposes.

Comment: In this case I don't think you can get the file bites and put them on a json this way. If you really want it in that json you could try encoding it in base64 before and then use base64 decode after receiving the data of the json. The sent data will be bigger but will be safely encoded on a string to be part of the json

Comment: The html file upliad control only stores the **local** path on the client of the file to be uploaded. You cannot programmatically set its value, that would be a huge security hole!

Comment: Thanks for the info. My goal is to avoid blank data getting written to the image field the after the form has been imported and then submitted again since the image data isn't included. It looks like it will be easier to check if the image is null and not overwrite it if there is data in it. This should be easy enough with two different SQL statements.

Comment: @Dharman The following example looks easy enough. How would I apply that to my 
SQL select statement?

    `SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
    "select foo from bar where baz = @baz",
    yourSqlConnection
    );


    SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
    parameter.ParameterName = "@baz";
    parameter.Value = "xyz";


    command.Parameters.Add(parameter);`

Comment: This close? It doesn't work. 
    `$sql = "DECLARE @Serial VARCHAR(15) SET @Serial = '$_GET[Serial]' SELECT * FROM setcrewreport WHERE Serial = @Serial";`

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying. Put the code in the question. It is difficult to read it in the comments.

Comment: Your attempt at `"parameterizing the SQL statement"` is flawed. You have two `type` placeholders but only assign a single value. As for re-populating a file input field - you will not be able to do that, even if you stored just the path rather than the Blob data. You might find that rendering the image * when user returns to continue ) with a link to upload another/again would work

Answer (score 0):

My original goal wasn't possible so I'm going an alternate route.

The SQL statement was parametarized as follows:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM setcrewreport WHERE Serial = ?");
$sql->bind_param("s", $_GET['Serial']);
$sql->execute();
```